# how to have Member name instead of his key in MDX statements SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx

There's an issue facing me. I am working on `SSAS` 2017 and I have dimensions used by 3 cubes. In one of my cube When I drag and drop my dimension member instead of getting the literal name of dimension member `([xxxx].[yyyy].[aaaa])` I got number [xxxx].[yyyy].&[1] ..
Please someone can tell me how to avoid this kind of behavior ?

To be more precise when i drag and drop in my mdx statement :

I have :

[Dim Sales Territory].[Sales Territory].[**1**] , [Dim Sales Territory].[Sales Territory].[**2**]

I want to get :

[Dim Sales Territory].[Sales Territory].[**Canada**] , [Dim Sales Territory].[Sales Territory].[**Australia**]

The [Dim Sales Territory] has key column [Sales Territory Id]

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you change the `MemberNamesUnique` property to true on the Sales Territory attribute in the Dim Sales Territory dimension editor and redeploy you’re cube then the drag and drop member unique name reference should change.

But my question is why you want to do this? Do you just want the code to be more readable? Are the names unique?

By the way, you will want to edit your question to put an `&` on member unique names which reference by key (`[Dim Sales Territory].[Sales Territory].&[1]`). If you omit these `&` then you reference the name property of an attribute. If truly you aren’t getting an `&` then the problem is that you have used the wrong column as the name column and have already set MemberNamesUnique=true.

Comment: Hello GregGalloway , Thank you for your answer. my goal is to have an easy readable code. You right for the missing "& ". thanks again

Comment: I want to have significant column name when wirting MDX expressions in my CALCULATE Tab in Visual studio. When drga and drop column in SQL server mangement studio I have a significant name but when try to create calulated Member in visula studio I have number instead of column name

Comment: Be aware that if the member names change because of changes in source systems your code will silently return through wrong numbers. In many ways using keys is safer unless you are confident the member names won’t change.